# Adding Module Causes Install Screen

Tags: module, magento2.2, exception

**[EDIT]**

Added screenshot showing can't run any of the CLI commands being suggested:

[image: CLI not working]

**[/EDIT]**

Implemented **add new table** official learning module (http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-a-new-table-to-database/) with no issues.

Implemented **add new product attribute** official learning module (http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/), and the `# magento setup:upgrade` step yields:

> magento_user@ubuntu:/var/www/html/magento.dev/app/code/Learning/ClothingMaterial/Setup#
>   magento setup:upgrade
>       Notice: Undefined index: websites in /var/www/html/magento.dev/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php
>   on line 248

Now I'm getting the **install** screen when I visit the store.

> Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters.  Click
>   'Agree and Set Up Magento' or read Getting Started to learn more.

Tried uninstalling the module `# magento module:disable Learning_ClothingMaterial --clear-static-content` and re-running `# magento setup:upgrade` amd `# magento setup:di:compile` but upgrade yields same error as above and compile yields:

> [Exception]   Warning: array_replace_recursive(): Argument #1 is not
>   an array in /var/www/html/magento.dev/vendor/magento/fram
>   ework/App/DeploymentConfig/Writer.php on line 135

It's impressive that following along with an official tutorial causes this level of destruction. Really hope there's an easy fix, as have had to re-install a half-dozen times now due to very similar issues.

Env: a vanilla composer CE 2.2 sandbox, on a bare metal Ubuntu 16 LAMP with PHP 7.1.

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to uninstall it:**

-> go to Database

-> go to `setup_module`

-> find `Learning_ClothingMaterial`

-> delete row

-> clear cache with `php bin/magento cache:clean`

-> clear generated by deleting content of the folder `/generated`

-> run setup upgrade with `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

-> recompile website with `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

**Update**

Not sure why you do not need to use `php bin/magento` because the magento commands should be in the bin folder.

I can tell you in developer mode you need to add `'-f'` to the command like `php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy`

I can also tell you if its not the `bin/magento` and you are still getting the `'there are no commands defined in the ... namespace'` it means that a class was not used (on top of you php file you need to include your classes by adding `'use Magento/.../..."` or badly used in the `__construct` of your php files.

You can just delete the module files and directories that you created , delete the `setup_module` and recompile.

If you want to get the module working then you need to go and comment out every class that you used until it works.

To provide more assistance on that i will need to see your code.

Comment: Deleted _Learning_ClothingMaterial_ from _setup_module_ table, and deleted content from _/generated_.  `# magento cache:clean` fails: `[Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] There are no commands defined in the "cache" namespace.`

Comment: Added screenshot to OP showing CLI output for the commands you recommended.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Running `export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/html/magento.dev/bin` makes `magento` a shortcut for `php bin/magento`. Static content deployment fails with `-f` as well. All custmizations added were copy/pasted from [this official magento tutorial](http://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/), so if the usings or contructors are erroneous... Yes, I deleted all flat file content added for the tutorial. As such, there's no code for you to see... this was a functioning **vanilla** CE 2.2 sandbox with **no customization** apart from the two training modules noted in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your custom module module.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
</module>
```